# How to combine a slow moving observable with the most recent value of a fast moving observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

A friend asked me this - I thought it was a good question so I am reposting it and my answer here:

I have these two streams:

```
var slowSource = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var fastSource = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
```

and I’d like to combine them so that I produce output pairs which contain
- The next value from slowSource
- The most recent value from fastSource

I only want one output pair per value from slowSource. For example, the first three output values might look something like this:

```
0,8
1,18,
2,28
```

A join gets me close but I end up with more than one output per slowSource (due to the way that the durations overlap, I guess):

```
var qry = slowSource.Join(
          right: fastSource,
          leftDurationSelector: i => fastSource,
          rightDurationSelector: j => fastSource,
          resultSelector: (l, r) => {return new {L = l, R = r};})
```

.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

Using a GroupJoin and a Select produces output that looks about right:

```
var qry2 = slowSource.GroupJoin(
              right: fastSource,
              leftDurationSelector: i => fastSource,
              rightDurationSelector: j => fastSource,
              resultSelector: (l, r) => {return new {L= l, R = r};}
              )
          .Select(async item => {
            return new {L = item.L, R = await item.R.FirstAsync()};})
          .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

However, this doesn’t feel like a great approach; there must be a better way that uses the other combinators to do stuff like this in a simpler way. Is there?

Answer (score 3):

How about this overload of Zip which combines an `IObservable` with an `IEnumerable`. It uses MostRecent() to get a sample of the latest value of a stream as the enumerable.

```
slowSource.Zip(fastSource.MostRecent(0), (l,r) => new {l,r})
```

Answer (score 1):

Observable.CombineLatest http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211991(v=vs.103).aspx can help and then you need to resample the fastSource at the rate of the slowSource.

```
var combinedObservable = slowSource.CombineLatest
    ( fastSource.Sample(slowSource)
    , (s,f)=>new {s,f}
    );
```

Comment: I considered this approach but went with Zip because it avoids the double subscription to slowSource. This way certainly has a more idiomatic feel to it for me though somehow. However, there is a bug here: Any `slowSource` events propagated before `fastSource`'s first event are missed. (The purpose of the argument to `MostRecent` in my answer is to define what to send in this instance)

Comment: Given the spec I'm not sure it is a bug. If you want the ''most recent'' from fast source and there has been no event from fast source then what? What does your solution return in the case you describe? Does it return a null for ''r'' in the case slowSource is earlyier than fastSource?

Comment: I was going on the requirement **"I only want *one output pair per value from slowSource*"**. MostRecent allows you to specify the "null" value. Granted the "only" leaves things open to interpretation a little bit, but it seems to me slow source events shouldn't be omitted. A `StartsWith()` is enough to adjust it if necessary.