# How to merge observables on a regular interval?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to merge two sensor data streams on a regular interval and I'm having trouble doing this properly in Rx.  The best I've come up with is the the sample below, however I doubt this is optimal use of Rx.

Is there a better way?

I've tried Sample() but the sensors produce values at irregular intervals, slow (>1sec) and fast (<1sec).  Sample() only seems to deal with fast data.

```
Observable<SensorA> sensorA = ... /* hot */
Observable<SensorB> sensorB = ... /* hot */

SensorA lastKnownSensorA;
SensorB lastKnownSensorB;

sensorA.Subscribe(s => lastKnownSensorA = s);
sensorB.Subscribe(s => lastKnownSensorB = s);

var combined = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Where(t => _lastKnownSensorA != null)
    .Select(t => new SensorAB(lastKnownSensorA, lastKnownSensorB)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think @JonasChapuis 's answer may be what you are after, but there are a couple of issues which might be problematic:

- `CombineLatest` does not emit a value until all sources have emitted at least one value each, which can cause loss of data from faster sources up until that point. That can be mitigated by using `StartWith` to seed a [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) or default value on each sensor stream.
- `Sample` will not emit a value if no new values have been observed in the sample period. I can't tell from the question if this is desirable or not, but if not there is in interesting trick to address this using a "pace" stream, described below to create a *fixed* frequency, instead of the *maximum* frequency obtained with `Sample`.

To address the `CombineLatest` issue, determine appropriate null values for your sensor streams - I usually make these available via a static `Null` property on the type - which makes the intention very clear. For value types use of `Nullable<T>` can also be a good option:

```
Observable<SensorA> sensorA = ...  .StartWith(SensorA.Null);
Observable<SensorB> sensorB = ...  .StartWith(SensorB.Null);
```

*N.B. Don't make the common mistake of applying `StartWith` only to the output of `CombinedLatest`... that won't help!*

Now, if you need regular results (which naturally could include repeats of the most recent readings), create a "pace" stream that emits at the desired interval:

```
var pace = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Then combine as follows, omitting the pace value from results:

```
var sensorReadings = Observable.CombineLatest(
    pace, sensorA, sensorB,
    (_, a, b) => new SensorAB(a,b));
```

It's also worth knowing about the [`MostRecent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229751(v=vs.103).aspx) operator which can be combined with `Zip` very effectively if you want to drive output at the speed of a specific stream. See these answers where I demonstrate that approach: [How to combine a slow moving observable with the most recent value of a fast moving observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980512/how-to-combine-a-slow-moving-observable-with-the-most-recent-value-of-a-fast-mov/20980513#20980513) and the more interesting tweak to handle multiple streams: [How do I combine three observables such that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422994/how-do-i-combine-three-observables-such-that/27424363#27424363)

Comment: I really like the idea of a pace stream, however in this case I would still need to Sample the result as Sensors can burst data (10-50 per second) and it would result in a lot of unnecessary allocations.  I don't think  MostRecent+Zip is practical in this case as either sensor can burst or be really slow at times (cool trick though)

Comment: OK. By requiring minimal allocations you are introducing a new requirement which changes things so significantly it's practically a different question and the focus would need to be elsewhere. I'm curious as to why you need this (does your system exhibit undesirable effects due to GC pressure?). A lot more context would be needed to provide a good answer here, particularly understanding the nature of the sensor data stream. Avoiding allocations generally involves careful consideration of data type use and re-use.

Comment: Applying `Sample` on both sensor streams to limit the source data would be an obvious way to limit downstream allocations of course - but certainly wouldn't be the whole story. Essentially, you would want to try and engineer the end-to-end stream so that most allocations are at the point of origin, and make those efficient through re-use. Bothering about all that is predicated on there being an actual rather than imagined performance problem though! That kind of code requires great skill and is expensive to maintain.

Comment: Why would you want to allocate lots of objects if there is no need for it?  My example above doesn't overallocate.  My issue is that my code doesn't really look like proper RX to me, however I can't find a way without negative side-effects.  Or anyway that produces the right results for that matter.  Like I said I can't use Sample() because it doesn't fire when the streams are slow.  So even the combinelatest + pacer doesn't work.

Comment: If you append the `Sample()` to the `sensorA` and `sensorB` declarations above, before the `StartWith`, the slowness of the individual streams won't matter.

Comment: On allocating lots of objects: increasingly optimizing your code gets increasingly expensive. The pursuit of perfecting your code is a lofty goal, but without infinite resources you should pick your battles to align with the needs of the customer. Writing maximally GC efficient code is hard, and is only cost effective in a certain scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `CombineLatest()` operator to merge the latest values of the sensors every time either produces a value, followed by `Sample()` to ensure a max frequency of one measurement per second?

```
sensorA.CombineLatest(sensorB, (a, b) => new {A=a, B=b}).Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
```

Comment: Tried something like this.  I found 2 issues.  If both sensors are bursting (10+ ticks per second), I end up with a lot unnecessary allocations from the CombineLatest.  Second, Sample() doesn't fire if it hasn't received anything for over a second.